# PHP Page Won't Reload with # HTML

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, updating

I am using HTML and jQuery to create a website for a company. It is a mobile website, I used jQuery and HTML to create a site that loads all at one time (all the coding is on one page, and when you click a link it changes the page with a #pagename in the URL bar. So once you load the main website you don't have to have an internet connection to load it any further. I started it out all in HTML then decided I was an idiot for doing that because there are over 500 values that are going ot be on the site. So I changed it to PHP and used mySQL for the database. I then coded the page to show the information off the site. The problem that I ran into is that with the PHP coding it isn't reloading the page to the new page when you click on it. That might so confusing so let me explain better and show you.

Here is how the site is suppose to work : http://communitymedics.com/app/

Here is how the site is working with the PHP code : http://communitymedics.com/app/index2.php

```
<?php 

$result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT state FROM hospital ORDER BY state");

echo "<div data-role='page' id='locations-hospital'>";
echo "<div data-role='header' data-position='fixed'>";
echo "<h1>Locations</h1>";
echo "<a href='#' data-rel='back' data-theme='a'>Back</a>";
echo "</div><div data-role='content'><ul data-role='listview'><br><li data-role='list-divider'>Select State</li>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<li><a href='#" . $row['state'] . "'>" . $row['state'] . "</a></li>";
  }
  ;
?>
```

If you notice, when you click on the state, Indiana for example, it doesn't do anything, the link in the URL doesn't change and it won't change to the Indiana page.

Any idea on how to fix this. In the end the idea is to have it similar to what the entire HTML page is right now, not sure what I am missing in the PHP code that is causing it not to open that page.

My other issue is if you're on the #locationhospitals page you will notice the header that is suppose to say "select state" at the top isn't showing, like the spacing isn't working right. Any idea on this?

THANKS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're using were just anchors, which only act on the page loaded into the browser already, allowing you to jump to different points in the document. What doesn't happen is a new request to the web server. No server request, no PHP runs.

So how do we fix this?

Well, since you're now using PHP and a database you MUST maintain a connection to the server in order to use your application (well, browser caching aside, but that's a different question for a different day). You're already using jQuery, awesome!!

Basically, you're going to have a container, we'll call it

```
<div id="foo"></div>
```

Using jQuery, bind click events to the various "buttons" we'll call them. When someone clicks on one we'll make an AJAX request to your PHP to grab the data and display it inside the container. When someone hits another "button", we'll replace the old data with the new data. You could even use the script you have right there if you really wanted to...

That is to say without some wicked serious modification. mysql_* is deprecated, and you should switch over to mysqli. I don't see where your data params are coming in, so make sure they're clean before passing them to your query as well.

Since OP asked, here is a super quick and dirty way to bind a click event to some element on the page and then use that to make the request

```
jQuery("#any_element_with_this_id").click(function(clickedElementReference){
    jQuery("#foo").empty();//might as well go ahead and empty our our container
        jQuery.get("phpscript.php",{"state_id":"IN"},function(dataFromYourScript){
            jQuery("#foo").html(dataFromYourScript);//insert our fresh data, hot off the press
        },"HTML");
    });
```

This is wicked dirty, and probably doesn't even work, but it should give you a place to start.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. I'm not to experienced with Jquery unfortunately. Any idea what coding I could use to bind click events with the buttons that would replace the old data with the new? I understand exactly what you mean though, if I can make it refresh that page upon clicking that should fix all of the issues that I am happening, just trying to figure out how to make that happen.

Comment: I can write some skeleton code for you, but you're gonna have to do the rest as homework ;) Read this first of all: http://api.jquery.com/category/events/

Comment: I love the opportunity to learn, jQuery has been a slow process for me just because it tends to confuse to between PHP and jQuery coding. I'll take a look at that link.

Comment: jQuery was a dream come true for me, and a joy to learn! I'll defend it to the death from the likes of Dojo ;)

Comment: Yeah there is a bunch you'll have to learn --> fwgun is right with the direction you want to go in...to learn jquery try: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ <-- that will take you a day I'd say. Pretty good answer^ for the amount of things that you might need help with. Don't forget to mark it as the answer ;)

Comment: Thanks for the code up there, although I'm confused as crap! Ha! I wonder if there is non-Jquery way to do this. I just don't understand it enough to be about to make it work right I don't think. I'll play around with it some to see what I can figure out with the Jquery though.

Comment: I already had a decent amount of JS experience when I learned jQuery, so I was a little ahead, but it took all of an hour or two to get up and running with it and using it everywhere I needed to, and there is still plenty more for me to learn.

Comment: @Zarazthuztra but I need dojo for web map development XD

Comment: @user1567453 Ew. Find a jQuery plugin :P

Comment: @fwgun You don't want to see the raw JavaScript way to do that (you should learn anyway, but trust me for now) Hit me up if you've got a specific question about how something works.

Comment: I'm curious if there is a PHP way to refresh a page when the anchor is activated.

Comment: Well, keep in mind that PHP runs on the server. Technically it doesn't do anything but process some code and return some HTML to the browser (n the case of a page) so unless you're making an HTTP or HTTPS connection to your server, the PHP will not run.

Comment: yeah good point, basically it would be jQuery or javascript to do it then. I guess I could do a onclick refresh

Comment: Well keep in mind, jQuery is just a JavaScript library. You're still writing JavaScript, it's just that jQuery has abstracted a lot of the painful parts away (like writing AJAX code)

Comment: I tried this and almost had it working, not totally though...

http://communitymedics.com/app/index2.php

<script>
function gototab(reload)
   {
    window.location.hash = '#location-hospital';
    window.location.reload(true);
   }
</script>

onclick="gototab();"